# EF Core DbSet AddAsync method: Should the async method be used in 100% of the cases?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, valuetask

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.addasync?view=efcore-5.0) on the `AddAsync` method states that

> This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.

Is this still up to date, as the method does return a `ValueTask` and thus, in the synchronous way there should be no further Task-related allocations?

**Update / Follow-up question**

Why does `AddRangeAsync` not return a `ValueTask` ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.addrangeasync?view=efcore-5.0))?

Comment: See https://thesharperdev.com/ef-cores-addasync-v-add-method/